# Simplest way to find the element that occurs the most in each column

Tags: python, list, matrix

Suppose I have

```
data =
[[a, a, c],
 [b, c, c],
 [c, b, b],
 [b, a, c]]
```

I want to get a list containing the element that occurs the most in each column: `result = [b, a, c]`, what is the easiest way to do that ?

I use Python 2.6.6

Comment: Your title asks for "the max of each column"; your question asks for "the element that occurs the most".  I'm assuming from your example you want the latter?  Do you care about what happens in the case of ties?

Comment: @DSM yes the latter, what do you mean by ties ?

Comment: What do you want `[a, a, b, b]` to return?

Comment: @DSM doesn't matter, say the first element if we have the same number of occurrences.

Comment: Is the data numeric (e.g. ints or floats)?  Or are there any other constraints on the data type of the elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In statistics, what you want is called the *mode*.  The scipy library (http://www.scipy.org/) has a `mode` function, in `scipy.stats`.

```
In [32]: import numpy as np

In [33]: from scipy.stats import mode

In [34]: data = np.random.randint(1,6, size=(6,8))

In [35]: data
Out[35]: 
array([[2, 1, 5, 5, 3, 3, 1, 4],
       [5, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2, 5, 3],
       [2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1],
       [2, 4, 1, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5],
       [4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4],
       [2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3]])

In [36]: val, count = mode(data, axis=0)

In [37]: val
Out[37]: array([[ 2.,  4.,  5.,  5.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  3.]])

In [38]: count
Out[38]: array([[ 4.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  3.,  2.]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension plus [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

[Counter(col).most_common(1)[0][0] for col in zip(*data)]
```

`zip(*data)` rearranges your list of lists to become a list of columns instead. `Counter()` objects count how often anything appears in the input sequence, and `.most_common(1)` gives us the most popular element (plus it's count).

Provided your input is single character strings, that gives:

```
>>> [Counter(col).most_common(1)[0][0] for col in zip(*data)]
['b', 'a', 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

Is the data hashable?  If so, a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) will be helpful:

```
[Counter(col).most_common(1)[0][0] for col in zip(*data)]
```

It works because `zip(*data)` transposes the input data yielding 1 column at a time.  The counter then counts the elements and stores the counts in a dictionary with the counts as values.  `Counters` also have a `most_common` method which returns a list of the "N" items with the highest counts (sorted from most counts to least counts).  So, you want to get the first element in the first item in the list returned by most_common which is where the `[0][0]` comes from.

e.g.

```
>>> a,b,c = 'abc'
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> data = [[a, a, c],
...  [b, c, c],
...  [c, b, b],
...  [b, a, c]]
>>> [Counter(col).most_common(1)[0][0] for col in zip(*data)]
['b', 'a', 'c']
```

Comment: and if additionally we want also the counts associated to the output: [b, a, c], with counts [2, 2, 3], it it possible with Counter ?

Comment: @shn -- See my explanation.  You could get something like `[(b,2),(a,2),(c,3)]` by simply removing one of the `[0]` in there.

Comment: Oh I use python 2.6.6, it seems that Counter is not supported with this version

Comment: @shn -- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/ is a version which aims to work for python2.5

Comment: @shn -- http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l383 -- I haven't tried it, but you might be able to use the python2.7 source code for Counter directly on python2.6.6 as well.  See the link I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without using the collections module

```
def get_most_common(data):

    data = zip(*data)
    count_dict = {}
    common = []
    for col in data:
        for val in col:
            count_dict[val] = count_dict.get(val, 0) + 1
        max_count = max([count_dict[key] for key in count_dict])
        common.append(filter(lambda k: count_dict[k] == max_count, count_dict))

    return common

if __name__ == "__main__":

    data = [['a','a','b'],
            ['b','c','c'],
            ['a','b','b'],
            ['b','a','c']]

    print get_most_common(data)
```